# Tomcat performance issue

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, ssl, wicket

I've got a web application that's running really slowly and occasionally hanging.  It's a school-related Wicket app with reporting and editing, and also a servlet which is used by automated clients to get/post data via HTTPS.

During busy times where a lot of editing/uploading/downloading is going on, the app becomes sluggish and unresponsive.  I get Wicket "PageMap still locked" errors.  Tomcat seems to keep chugging along.  Memory usage is managable, about 50M.

I set up YourKit to get some profiling info, and during a busy period found that 81% of the Tomcat CPU time is spent here:

```
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run()
org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket$SocketConnection.runIt(Object[])
org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.processConnection(MsgContext)
org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.receive(Msg, MsgContext)
org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.read(MsgContext, byte[], int, int)
java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(byte[], int, int)
java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(byte[], int, int)
java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill()
java.net.SocketInputStream.read(byte[], int, int)
[Wall Time]  java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(FileDescriptor, byte[], int, int, int)
```

In this app I've got about 250 clients polling the server over SSL asking for updates every 30 seconds.  Most of the time, this quickly returns an empty response.  Occasionally, there's a flurry of DB activity, and a whole slew of data (a few MB) may be sent back to the client.

So what's this 81% activity from?  Could a few clients with really slow connections bog down tomcat threads by causing it to wait for incoming request bodies?

Anyone seen anything like this, or have any advice on how to test/troubleshoot/fix this?

Comment: How big are the data sets that are being passed across the wire?

Comment: When a single record is edited on the server, all clients download just the modified records.  1 or 2 k.  If a client is reset, it downloads all data for a school.  Probably never more than 5 MB.

Comment: Downloading all of the data sounds fairly nasty.  Does the client really need all of that data?  Can you do some sort of paging?  Additionally, how is the client getting the data?  Scripting calls to a web service of some sort?

Comment: Are you sure CPU time is spent here, versus just simple waiting? use 'top' or something to see if CPU usage is way up.

What version of Tomcat, Java?

Why not increase the heap a little to see if it helps? you have evidence that a great deal of garbage is collected, which indicates the system is under memory pressure. How are you sure your app isn't using all memory?

Comment: @popester: Client does indeed need the data.  I could do it in batches, but that would complicate things a lot.  I'm streaming it out, so it should support large sets.

Comment: @Sean: I believe tomcat CPU usage is high during heavy loads, it spikes at 25%, on what I believe is a quad-core machine, so I think it's totally utilizing one of the cores (I'm a bit fuzzy on the hardware stuff though)

Comment: Tomcat version is 5.5.27
Java is version jre1.5.0_19\bin\client\jvm.dll

The heap size is set to 1400 MB.  When I set it higher than that, Tomcat refuses to start. I believe this is because it's 32-bit java. There's 8 GB available on the server, which is also running the MS-SQL database.  Should I upgrade to 64 bit java and allocate more RAM?

Comment: what are your JVM parameters.. increasing the heap might not be the answer.

Comment: The only custom VM parameters is setting the max heap: -Xmx1400m

Raising it higher than this prevents Tomcat from starting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set up a test environment and try to reproduce this with a load test.
That way you can isolate the cause. Otherwise there are too many factors.
Also, this way you can try fixes without jeopardizing your prod env.

Answer (score 0):

The memory use is probably the cause.
You should check the memory use for the java process to see how much it's getting.
If it's not getting enough you have to set the Xmx jvm parameter wherever these are set for tomcat.

Comment: Testing today shows the GC is stable, since I increased the JPA entity cache size.  The app is using about 1.1 GB of RAM.